# Identifying What Javascript is Running on a <span> through Chrome Inspector or Firebug

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, inspect

I am working on a site that has info being generated dynamically into `<span></span>` tags through jQuery. The span has a class of "Price" and an id of a Product Code and it's being generated from a JSON data sheet according to the ID. The problem is, this is part of a much bigger framework and I can't seem to find where the Javascript is that's accomplishing this so I can troubleshoot it.

I'm trying to figure out how to find that out using Google Chrome Inspector or Firebug. I'm assuming the page records this info when it's loaded but I can't seem to find where that info would lie. I know this may be pretty basic but I new to the Inspectors beyond just reading the HTML and CSS. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the javascript console in your browser and use this:

```
$("#ProductCode").data("events")
```

Then if you expand the object you'll see the events.